# Cocos3D handleTouch:ofType: not recognized

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

When I try to activate touch move support by uncommenting following function (as recommended in documentation):

```
///*
-(void) ccTouchMoved: (UITouch *)touch withEvent: (UIEvent *)event {
    [self handleTouch: touch ofType: kCCTouchMoved];
}
 //*/
```

I get compilation error:

```
No visible @interface for 'CC3HelloWorldLayer' declares the selector 'handleTouch:ofType:'
```

[image]

This function is declared in CCLayer.h from which CC3layer inherits.

**What is the cause of that strange error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `handleTouch:ofType:` method is defined in `CC3Layer.m` as a protected method, and needs to be redeclared in any subclass files that use it (it has no public visibility).

The redeclaration is missing from the `CC3HelloWorldLayer.m` file due to an oversight. I'll fix that in a future release.

In the meantime, add the following to the top of your `CC3HelloWorldLayer.m` file:

```
@interface CC3Layer (TemplateMethods)
-(BOOL) handleTouch: (UITouch*) touch ofType: (uint) touchType;
@end
```

See the `TileLayer.m` and `CC3DemoMashUpLayer.m` files for examples.

...Bill

Answer (score 0):

Either `handleTouch:ofType:` is not declared as a (public) method in CCLayer.h or the CC3HelloWorldLayer class does not inherit from CCLayer.h, either directly or through its parent class CC3Layer.

You do say that both are the case but I can't quite believe it because that would be the only two reasons why this error might occur.